# Does group action $G$ on $A$ respect the algebraic structure of $A$?

Tags: group-theory

Say $A$ itself is a multiplicative group,
for all $g \in G$, is $g \cdot (xy) = (g \cdot x)y$ necessarily true?

Similarly, if $R$ is a ring, should it always be true that $g(x + y) = g(x) + g(y)$?

Does this extend to $k$-vector spaces? $g(cx + y) = cg(x + y)$, for $c \in k$?

Comment: Your examples are a bit weird. The most natural possible meaning of "respect the algebraic structure of $A$" would be that every map $x\mapsto g\cdot x$ is a morphism for the structure you consider on $A$, but this is not what you ask in your first and third example (and in the second, it's really only a part of what you should ask). That being, said, I think a general answer to your question is **NO**.

Comment: What do you mean by "$A$ itself is a multiplicative group"?  A group only needs one operation.  This is commonly called multiplication and could always be called that.  Consider $\mathbb{Q}$ under addition, forget its usual multiplication and call the addition "multiplication" and use it for $A$.  Now, use $\mathbb{Z}$ as $G$  and the action of $G$ on $A$ is based on the (now remembered) multiplication of $\mathbb{Q}$.  This would seem to be a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

A bit longer answer: Consider a group $G$ acting on some group/ring/vector space $A$. Assume that the action preserves the algebraic structure of $A$. Now pick a bijection $f:A \to A$ and define a new algebraic structure via it:
$$a\star b:=f(a)f(b)$$

(analogously for addition and/or scalar multiplication) You can easily check that $(A,\star,\cdots)$ is again a group/ring/vector space. Note that the original group action does not depend on the new binary operation I just defined.

Now take $f$ to switch only two elements and keep others in place. If you pick those elements carefully then you will find out that the property $g(x\star y)=(gx)\star y$ no longer holds. I think it is enough to take $x,y\in A$ such that $gx\neq gy$ for some $g\in G$.